# Why am I getting low disk space usage?

Tags: disk-usage

I have problems understanding my disk space usage. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I am recently going low on disk space and I cannot understand why. Here is the result of du (only largest folders).

```
716.0K  Videos
1.1M    giorgio2.pdf
1.7M    2011_Thesis_Caroline_Ferdinand.pdf   
2.1M    031022_1.pdf
2.4M    dgfem
29.7M   aux
362.6M  Papers
479.3M  Desktop
588.6M  Documents
1.8G    vtk
3.0G    Dropbox
38.0G   Pictures
105.9G  Music
```

Here is the result of df -h

```
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/sda6       322G  304G  1.4G 100% /
 udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
 tmpfs           1.6G  940K  1.6G   1% /run
 none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock 
 none            3.9G  736K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
```

What I don't understand is where the 304G used come from. The result of du does not sum up to that amount. That make me difficult to free space (as you see I have only 1.4G available). What am I missing here?

I add an image of Disk Usage Analyzer. The point is that the first 10 largest folders sum up to less than 165G. But still my home folder uses 312G.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 12.10. See [my question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206860/ubuntu-12-10-recognizes-me-only-3gb-of-free-space) for further information.

Comment: Do you have the `.xsession-errors.old` file in your home directory? If so, what is the size of this one?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. It is 148.4G. What's the point of this huge file?? I guess I can delete it...

Comment: You should [delete the file](http://askubuntu.com/a/217045/62483). I created a more generalized question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/314723/62483)

Comment: Please, help us and create an entry [on the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1000775) and sign it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get the largest files in a directory, including hidden dotfiles, try running:

```
du -h .* | sort -h
```